# Most efficient way to have UIViewController view fill out all of usable space?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xib

I have a universal single view app which has a `UINavigationBar` `toolbar` at the bottom, then the `UIViewController` `view` takes up the rest of the space.

I usually do everything programmatically, so for the longest time I've been calculating the `UIViewController's` `view` `frame` manually in `loadView`, taking into account all of the components that a device could have i.e. home indicator height on new iPhone device, opaque status bar on old devices.

However, with all the new devices I'm finding this way to be inefficient and have thought about switching to a storyboard or xib. I've never really worked with these so I don't understand how it works. For instance, if I create a storyboard with the ViewController's view taking the entire size of the usable area, will this translate for all devices? Will it resize correctly when there's rotation?

In general I'm kind of wondering, what is the most elegant / efficient way to create an app where the `UIViewController's` `view` takes up the entire usable area of the screen on all devices, including when the phone rotates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I usually do everything programmatically, so for the longest time I've been calculating the UIViewController's view frame manually in `loadView`

There was never any need to do that; you can just delete that code. The navigation controller itself will give its child view controller's view the correct frame!

All *you* have to do is provide the child view controller's views *subviews* with correct positioning. And *that* is something you should be doing just by giving them autolayout constraints, so that they will be correctly arranged no matter what size the view controller's view ends up being. You can do that in code or through a storyboard; it makes no difference.

> In general I'm kind of wondering, what is the most elegant / efficient way to create an app where the UIViewController's view takes up the entire usable area of the screen on all devices, including when the phone rotates?

The elegant efficient way is: do nothing. That is what already happens, automatically, with no input from you.

Comment: Thanks @matt. Has that changed? When I started doing it this way, this was like back in 2012. I can't remember why, maybe it was my own poor understanding or I think back then I had to reposition the view manually for some reason (maybe because of my wonky design). So are you saying that I should just stop overriding loadView, and if so, what would be the best method to attach subviews to the UIViewController's view? viewDidMoveToSuperview or whatever?

Comment: It was always wrong (and fruitless) to size the view controller's view yourself. It is (and always was) sized by its parent _after_ your `loadView`. Maybe your calculations were really good so you didn't notice this! — Just use a navigation controller with its toolbar showing and its navigation bar not showing (if desired) as your app's root view controller, and you'll automatically get exactly the effect you describe.

Comment: Of course it may be that you are inserting your view controller's view into another view controller's view in some weird manual way, which may also be wrong, but you have not shown that code so I can't comment.